# corona/lua error; attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'x'?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

This error has been baffling me. I have made a game (app) and when trying to cause a "game over" then change to my game over screen from the game screen I get this error.

Here are some pictures of the error and my blocks of code that the error associates with. I know it has to do with my endgame() function.

http://imgur.com/a/61Ap2

sorry if pictures make this difficult

Comment: Please include the code in your question. Posting screenshots of it isn't helping anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Post the code relevant to question, do not link to snapshots. Until then, all we can say is that error indicates `car` exists when `moveCar()` is called, but `car` does not have a field `x`; however we can't tell what `car` is from the code, how it was created, if x was set to nil somewhere, etc. Put some print statements of `car.x` in a few places, you might get more useful information and smaller scope of code to look at.